# How to execute a command from a scala script?

Tags: scala

I want to execute `mysqldump -u talkexchange -p --opt talkexchange > /talkmedia/backups/database_backup.sql` command from scala script. How do I go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like @0__ suggested with `sys.process._` but with a little tweak:

```
import sys.process._
import java.io.File
"mysqldump -u talkexchange -p --opt talkexchange" #> new File("/talkmedia/backups/database_backup.sql")
```

Otherwise the `>` will be interpreted as a parameter to `mysqldump`, instead of a redirection operator.

Comment: I get this error, error: not found: type File. I've imported java.io.File._

Comment: Sorry, the right import was `java.io.File` without the `_`, fixed it on the answer.